# Filterable SPFIeldUrl in default view

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss, field

I`v added a hyperlink (SPFieldUrl class) column (field) with GUI to my list.

Pity, but I cannot filter those values when viewing the list.
[alt text http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/5126/ss20090505152613.png](http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/5126/ss20090505152613.png)
(It reads that you cannot filter this column type)

Is there any way to have it easy filterable with clicking on columns besides creating a custom view?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you are using the url, you may be able to do something with calculated columns.

Another option is to use a text field rather than a url field - The url field type is effectively a combination of two fields, so you may be able to get what you are looking for by creating those two field seperately.

Comment: 2 columns would be too much, but possible. I just need a link to some other workspace.

Is it possible to make the value in SPFieldText (for example, value could be http://server/site/web) to make a clickable hyperlink?

Comment: That depends on the view you are using. It should be possible to set up a custom column type that renders text as a link and is still sortable, which would be the proper way to do it, but I'd probably just go with some jquery on the display page to add hyperlinks to text urls.